# comparing and sorting arraylist of values in hashmap java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, key-value

I have a hashmap

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> games = new hashmap<String, Arraylist<String>>();
```

it contains name as the key and list of games as the values.
like this:

```
A= [ cricket, soccer, tennis, baseball]
B= [soccer, badminton, rugby]
C= [cricket, badminton]
D= [rugby, cricket, soccer]
E= [cricket, baseball]
F= [tennis, rugby]
```

now i want to count the occurence of each value (criket, soccer etc.) and 
assign only one value to a key based on the occurence of values.
here, cricket occured 4 times, soccer occured 3 times and so on.
And compare the values of each key and check which values occured how many times.
Then i want to assign the value with the maximum occurence.
that is i want to have a hashmap which will be like this:

```
A= [ cricket] // because among its 4 values, cricket has occured maximum times.
B= [soccer] // among its 3 values, soccer has occured maximum times.
C= [cricket]
D= [cricket]
E= [cricket]
F= [rugby] // among its 2 values, rugby has occured maximum times which is 3.
```

And so on...
I have no clue on how to tackle this situation. So, please help me regarding this and 
give detailed info. 
thanks

Comment: You can create countMap map which will store gameName as key and number of occurange as value. And then iterate through games map and its all inner list and set value in countMap. After this it will be easier for you to tackle your problem.

Comment: I would say, instead of asking for solution, you could have tried it yourself and then if you are stuck at any position in your code, you could ask about it.

Comment: @NamanGala ..i tried by using for loop on entryset() and comparator but didn't know the exact implementation of the functions..thnxx anyway..i will keep this thing in mind for the next time..

Comment: You could have posted code here.. Someone might have given suggestions.. And also you would get info about best practices for your own code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume this algorithm can help your.

```
public void testAlgorithm(){
        Map<String, List<String>> map = this.generateDatasource();
        Map<String, Integer> numberMap = this.calculateHappeds(map);
        Map<String, String> rstMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            List<String> sports = map.get(key);
            Integer index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < sports.size(); i++) {
                if (numberMap.get(sports.get(i)) > numberMap.get(sports.get(index))) {
                    index = i;
                }
            }
            rstMap.put(key, sports.get(index));
        }
        for (String key : rstMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + " = " + " [ " + rstMap.get(key) + " ]");
        }
    }

    private Map<String, Integer> calculateHappeds(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
        Map<String, Integer> calculate = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            List<String> sports = map.get(key);
            for (String sport : sports) {
                if (calculate.containsKey(sport)) {
                    Integer count = calculate.get(sport);
                    count += 1;
                    calculate.put(sport, count);
                }else {
                    calculate.put(sport,1);
                }
            }
        }
        return calculate;
    }

    private Map<String, List<String>> generateDatasource() {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        a.add("cricket");
        a.add("soccer");
        a.add("tennis");
        a.add("baseball");
        map.put("A", a);

        List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
        b.add("soccer");
        b.add("badminton");
        b.add("rugby");
        map.put("B", b);

        List<String> c = new ArrayList<String>();
        c.add("cricket");
        c.add("badminton");
        map.put("C", c);

        List<String> d = new ArrayList<String>();
        d.add("rugby");
        d.add("cricket");
        d.add("soccer");
        map.put("D", d);

        List<String> e = new ArrayList<String>();
        e.add("cricket");
        e.add("baseball");
        map.put("E", e);

        List<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();
        f.add("tennis");
        f.add("rugby");
        map.put("F", f);
        return map;
    }
```

because rstMap is map, so the output is

```
D =  [ cricket ]
E =  [ cricket ]
F =  [ rugby ]
A =  [ cricket ]
B =  [ soccer ]
C =  [ cricket ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your easiest way is to create a class that extends your targetMap implementation (HashMap in this case). In your new class, keep a second Map for each of your value options to an Integer that keeps a count of the values in your ArrayList. Then override the #clear(), #put(), #putAll(), and #remove() methods to manage your second map. For Ex:

```
SHashMap extends HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>{
  HashMap<String,Integer> valMap;

  public void put(String key, ArrayList<String> vals){
    for(String s: vals){
        if(valMap.containsKey(s)){
            valMap.put(s,valMap.get(s)+1);
        }else{
            valMap.put(s,1);
        }
    }
    return super.put(key,vals); // Keep the hierarchy accurate
  }
}
```

Then, just add a simple getMax(String) method that checks valMap for the one with the highest count:

```
public String getMax(String key){
    String max = null;
    int countMax =0;
    for(String val:get(key)){
        if(valMap.get(val) > countMax){
            countMax = valMap.get(val);
            max = val;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Implement the #clear, #putAll, and #remove methods to appropriately adjust the data in valMap, as your needs and usage require. Depending on your usage, there are multiple ways to make this more efficient, but this should get you on the road.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class CountMap {

/*  data
    A= [ cricket, soccer, tennis, baseball]
    B= [soccer, badminton, rugby]
    C= [cricket, badminton]
    D= [rugby, cricket, soccer]
    E= [cricket, baseball]
    F= [tennis, rugby]*/

    public CountMap(){}

    private static Map<String,List<String>> testDdata= new HashMap<>(); 
    private static Map<String,Integer> sportsCoount= new HashMap<>(); 


    public static void main(String[] args){

        //prepare test data
        prepareTestData();

        prepareOutputMap();
    }

    private static void prepareOutputMap() {

        // sportsCoountMap is ready now
        for(String key:testDdata.keySet()){
            List<String> valueList= testDdata.get(key);

            for(String testValue:valueList){
                Integer value=sportsCoount.get(testValue);
                if(value!=null){
                    value++;
                    sportsCoount.put(testValue,value);
                }else{
                    value=1;
                    sportsCoount.put(testValue, value);
                }
            }
        }

        PriorityQueue<Entry<String, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(sportsCoount.size(), new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> arg0,
                    Entry<String, Integer> arg1) {
                return arg1.getValue().compareTo(arg0.getValue());
            }
        });
        pq.addAll(sportsCoount.entrySet());
        /*while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(pq.poll());
        }*/

        Entry<String,Integer> entry;

        List<String> keyList= new ArrayList<String>();
        keyList.addAll(testDdata.keySet());

        Collections.sort(keyList);
        for(String key:keyList){
            entry= pq.poll();
            System.out.println(key+"="+entry.getKey());
        }

    }

    private static void prepareTestData() {
        List<String> data1= new ArrayList<>();
        //cricket, soccer, tennis, baseball
        data1.add("cricket");
        data1.add("soccer");
        data1.add("tennis");
        data1.add("baseball");
        testDdata.put("A", data1);

        List<String> data2= new ArrayList<>();
        //soccer, badminton, rugby
        data2.add("soccer");
        data2.add("badminton");
        data2.add("rugby");
        testDdata.put("B", data2);

        List<String> data3= new ArrayList<>();
        //cricket, badminton
        data3.add("cricket");
        data3.add("badminton");
        testDdata.put("C", data3);

        List<String> data4= new ArrayList<>();
        //rugby, cricket, soccer
        data4.add("rugby");
        data4.add("cricket");
        data4.add("soccer");
        testDdata.put("D", data4);

         List<String> data5= new ArrayList<>();
        //cricket, baseball
        data5.add("cricket");
        data5.add("baseball");
        testDdata.put("E", data5);


    }
}
```

> ```
> > OutPut:-
> > 
> > A=cricket 
> > B=soccer 
> > C=rugby 
> > D=baseball 
> > E=badminton
> ```